# Another name for Plants

Tags: phrases, idioms, puns, animals, plants

Can I write 'blood-lacking living beings' instead of  just plainly writing 'plants'?       P.S: I have this assignment where creative names are appreciated!

Comment: What about amoebae and fungi and algae, not to mention bacteria?

Comment: bloodless, not blood-lacking. Even if you used what you wrote, it is not very creative and too long.

Comment: plenty of living *creatures* that live without blood: amoebas, arthropods,  erm... fungi. Anything wrong with *vegetation* or *flora*